# replace with php all alphanummeric chars with X or x (case sensitive)

Tags: php, replace

I have the following variables:

```
$var1 = "23 Jan 2014";
$var2 = "Some Text Here - More Text is written here";
```

How can I replace the text so the output looks like this:

```
$var1 = "XX Xxx XXXX";
$var2 = "Xxxx Xxxx Xxxx - Xxxx Xxxx xx xxxxxx xxxx";
```

Edit: The variables can change. I simply want to replace all A-Za-z0-9 from any variable with X (for capital letters), x (for small letters) and X (for numbers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double regular expressions - one for the upper case + numbers and one for the lower case. Something like this.

```
$var = preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9]/', 'X', $var);
$var = preg_replace('/[a-z]/', 'x', $var);
```

Answer (score 2):

Enhanced response to Hinz :)
In one shot :

```
$res = preg_replace(array('#[A-Z0-9]#', '#[a-z]#'), array('X', 'x'), $src);
```

Comment: I also like this approach better. But since OP didn't appear to know about regex, I thought I'd keep it even simpler. Have an upvote. :)

Comment: @JoelHinz : also i upvoted :) and very nice score 3K ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non reg-exp method. Personally I'd rather use the reg-exp method though.

```
<?php
$var1 = "23 Jan 2014";
echo convertStringToXX($var1);

$var2 = "Some Text Here - More Text is written here";
echo convertStringToXX($var2);

function convertStringToXX($input)
{
    $output = '';
    for($key = 0; $key < strlen($input); $key++)
    {
        $char = $input[$key];
        $ord = ord($char);

        if($ord >= 97 && $ord <= 122)
        {
            $output .= 'x';
        }
        elseif(($ord >= 65 && $ord <= 90) || ($ord >= 48 && $ord <= 57))
        {
            $output .= 'X';
        }
        else
        {
            $output .= $char;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```